Google App script send data to backend, how to authorize request?
I'm using a google app script to get data on change and sending it to my backend. All of it is working correctly but now I want to add authentication meaning that the request is coming from the app script connected to the correct google cloud project.
here is my manifes scopes
  "oauthScopes": [
    "openid",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ]

here is function
async function syncWithBackend(payload) {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  const options = {
    method: "post",
    headers: { 
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  };

  try {
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch('backend-url', options);
    const responseText = res.getContentText();
    ui.alert('Response from backend: ' + responseText); 
  } catch (error) {
    ui.alert('Error communicating with backend: ' + error.message + ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()); // Handle errors
  }
}

On my backend I check the following

const CLIENT_ID = ''

export async function verifyGoogleOAuthToken(token: string) {
  const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID)

  try {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: CLIENT_ID, // Ensure this matches your project's client ID
    })

    const payload = ticket.getPayload()
    console.log('Verified payload:', payload)

    // Check the email or project association if needed
    if (payload.iss !== 'https://accounts.google.com') {
      throw new Error('Invalid issuer')
    }

    return payload
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Token verification failed:', error.message)
    throw error
  }
}

but I get the following error Wrong number of segments in token
Preferably I would like to use google service account to validate
what should I do?
